# How do I determine what Scheme version a system is using?

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, scheme, redhat

I know this system is g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1). However, when I ran a scheme program that was developed on another system the code didn't work. Therefore, I want to see if it is because of different versions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're reporting the version of g++ that's on your system; this is probably unrelated to the version of Scheme that's installed on your system. What implementation of Scheme are you using? Put differently: what do you type at the command line in order to execute the program?